# Error: too few arguments to gtk_widget_new()

Tags: c, gtk

My O.S. is Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit).

I am having an error when I compiled my gtk+ program on command line terminal:

> second.cpp:8:43: error: too few arguments to function ‘GtkWidget* gtk_widget_new(GType, const gchar*, ...)’
>   /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:834:12: note: declared here

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window, *label;
    window=gtk_widget_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    label=gtk_label_new("LabelName");
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to rectify the error, this program is executing good when I write the program without the label Widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)`, not `window = gtk_widget_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)`.